# pip not found inside Github workflow while using container

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I've got this sample YML file for a GitHub Action:

```yaml
name: test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "**"

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: 3.7
      - name: Install pytest
        run: pip install pytest
```

It works just fine.  However, if I try to run inside of a Docker container:

```yaml
name: test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "**"

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: gcc:latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: 3.7
      - name: Install pytest
        run: pip install pytest
```

it fails with

```
/__w/_temp/7f078daf-76ef-4b47-a2d4-d587507806ff.sh: 1: pip: not found
```

How do I install pytest inside of the container?

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meantime? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Nothing yet sadly.